# MouseMove doesn't get the right coordinate points

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a label I am trying to drag. I click on the label, and on the MouseMove() event I am trying to relocate the position of the label.

```
public void MyLabel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
    ((Label)sender).Location = Cursor.Position;

    // I have also tried e.Location but none of these moves the label to
    // where the the cursor is, always around it, sometimes completely off
  }
}
```

Comment: That's because `Cursor.Position` is in **Screen** coords, but the Location() property needs to be in **Client** coords with respect to its Parent.  For your approach to work you'd need to use `PointToClient()` like this: `((Label)sender).Location = ((Label)sender).Parent.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);`  That will still "jump" on the initial drag, though, as the controls top/left corner will jump to the cursors position.  A more natural drag would be done like in the example by LarsTech below.

Answer (score 3):

You usually need to store the offset location of the initial mouse down point in the control, or else the control will move on you in a jittering fashion.  Then you just do the math:

```
Point labelOffset = Point.Empty;

void MyLabel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    labelOffset = e.Location;
  }
}

void MyLabel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    Label l = sender as Label;
    l.Location = new Point(l.Left + e.X - labelOffset.X,
                           l.Top + e.Y - labelOffset.Y);
  }
}
```